# The "you don't have full edit privileges" message is very unnoticeable

Tags: bug, design, editing

Honestly, I hadn't even realized it was there. The only reason I noticed it was because I though "hey, I don't think I have edit privileges yet" and *looked* for it. It's just plain text up at the top, and the text is awkwardly close to the top (shouldn't it have a top margin or something). It's extremely unnoticeable and looks like it's missing styles.

[image: Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.]

It should really have a border and different styling like the message you get when not logged in:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, these show up with a different color background on most sites so it's rather "loud". Hadn't noticed they don't show up like that here

Answer (score 1):

Without login I'm seeing this in Firefox:

[image]

Is this fixed or is the "logged in but without edit priviledges" message styled differently?

Comment: No. I tried as not being logged in, and it displays correctly. The message when logged in still doesn't display correctly.

Comment: @animuson aha, so that's the bug